# What should be the reason for debian getting stuck at Assertion '*_head == _item'?

Tags: debian, systemd, freeze

Whenever I'm trying to boot the Debian 11 is getting stuck at the following

```
Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)!

systemd[1]: Set hostname to <arm>.
systemd[1]: Failed to open netlink: Function not implemented
systemd[1]: Failed to allocate device monitor: Function not implemented
systemd[1]: Failed to allocate notification socket: Function not implemented
systemd[1]: Assertion '*_head == _item' failed at src/core/device.c:46, function device_unset_sysfs(). Aborting.
systemd[1]: Caught <ABRT>, dumped core as pid 799.
systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

Comment: OK, what machine/hardware is that, how did you install debian? Seeing you called this machine `arm`, what's your bootloading mechanism? Do you happen to know which kernel version this is? Is it the official kernel, or is this some hardware-vendor-specific kernel?

Comment: I'm getting these errors while messing with unusual kernel configurations, maybe that's a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the system originally installed as Debian 11, or has it been upgraded from an earlier release of Debian?

The fact that you are reaching the "Welcome to Debian..." message suggests the system is getting past the initramfs phase and reaching the real root filesystem, but on transitioning from the initramfs's mini-`systemd` to the real full-featured one, things quickly go wrong.

It certainly looks like `systemd` is trying to use some kernel features but is getting back "Function not implemented" errors, and then triggering an *assertion*.

(Assertions are primarily a development tool and they should never be a primary error-checking mechanism on a production-grade software. If a critical system component like `systemd` is hitting assertions, it means something is wrong in some way the developer did not really consider worth writing error messages for. If you can find out the root cause of your problem, you might want to create a bug report for `systemd`, describe what caused you to get here, and suggest a better error message.)

This might happen as a result of a failed upgrade, with the system attempting to run on a mix of old and new libraries, but normally the package dependencies should make such a situation impossible. Maybe if the system has crashed mid-upgrade at exactly the wrong time?

Perhaps you have added some package repositories that are incompatible with Debian 11, and the package management system has replaced some of the system's normal software packages with ones from the incompatible repository, and now the system cannot work as a result. In other words, you [may have made a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian): a freakish combination of unrelated, mutually incompatible packages.

A third possibility is if you have installed a custom kernel: it would then appear that your minimalist kernel configuration was *too* minimal, and some kernel features that are necessary for `systemd` to function were completely disabled.

Whatever the reason might be, the fact is the issue causes `systemd` (the process #1 on the system) to fail, which makes most ways to access the system non-viable. If you have installed a custom kernel, but still have a standard kernel installed, try telling your bootloader to boot the standard kernel instead. (I see your hostname is "arm". If it means you are using a processor of the ARM architecture, I think your bootloader might not necessarily be GRUB, but something else.)

Otherwise, you might try adding a boot parameter `init=/bin/bash` to give you a single shell session running as root as process #1: if this works, you can at least get some access to the system (while in a read-only state) to gather more information. In such a state, all of the normal userspace start-up processes are not executed, so you will have to do *everything* manually: that includes getting the root filesystem out of read-only mode, mounting any other filesystems as needed, and configuring any network interfaces if you need them.

If the `mount` command works, you could then do a `mount -o remount,rw /` to get write access to the root filesystem; then, if the package management tools are working, you could look at `/var/log/dpkg.log` to figure out which packages were updated or removed recently, and would have a chance of undoing the most recent package operations, which might have caused the problem. If the network configuration commands don't work at this point, you might have to download any necessary packages on a different computer and transfer them to this computer on a USB stick or other removable media.

If a large number of packages has been replaced/removed recently, and/or you find the package management tools don't work, you might have reached the point where it's going to be simpler to just backup any salvageable data files and reinstall the system.